# Repeat Div tag multiple times . I want to repeate the div tag whose id is block_container after clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mMXi.png)Can any one please tell  me how to repeat the div tag whose id is `block_container`. I am new to this UI design So I don't understand how to do this. This code contains also tiles using struts2

```
 <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <div class="CustomAttributesBlock GroupBoxBlock">
            <div id="TableWithServerHosts">

                <div class="clearfix">
                    <bean:define id="addFunction">
                        JavaScript:addCustomAttributeSearchForMaintenance('MaintenanceLineItemsAdvancedSearchPageForm', 'MaintenanceLineItemsAdvancedSearch_ADD_MAIN_LINE_ITEM_ATTRIBUTE_SEARCH.do')
                    </bean:define>
                    <h3>
                        <fmt:message key="supportLicenses.AdvancedSearch.FieldLabel.searchMaintenanceLineItemAttributes" />
                    </h3>
                    <a class="CustomAttributesAddDetail Buttons secondary add" href="<%=addFunction%>" id="BAConfigHosts_AddServerHost"> <fmt:message key="supportLicenses.AdvancedSearch.FieldLabel.addSearchAttribute" />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="block_container">

                    <div id="bloc1">
                        <s:select list="%{advSearchBean.metaDataMap}" headerKey="-1" headerValue="" onChange="newFunction(this);"/>
                    </div>

                     <div id="bloc2" style="display">
                        <tiles2:insertTemplate template="/operations/Entitlements/struts2/SearchOperatorTile.jsp" flush="true">
                        <tiles2:putAttribute name="propertyName" type="string" value="advSearchBean.textCustomSearchQualifier"/>
                        </tiles2:insertTemplate>  
                        <s:textfield name="advSearchBean.textCustom" theme="simple" cssClass="form"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="bloc4" style="display:none;">
                        <s:radio name="advSearchBean.boolCustom" list="#{'true':'Yes', 'false':'No', '':'None'}" theme="simple" cssClass="form" />
                    </div>

                    <div id="bloc5" style="display:none;">
                        <tiles2:insertTemplate template="/operations/Entitlements/struts2/SearchOperatorTile.jsp" flush="true">
                        <tiles2:putAttribute name="formName" value="MaintenanceLineItemsAdvancedSearchPageForm"/>
                        <tiles2:putAttribute name="propertyName" type="string" value="advSearchBean.numCustomSearchQualifier"/>
                        <tiles2:putAttribute name="propertyType" value="numeric"/>
                        </tiles2:insertTemplate>
                        <s:textfield name="advSearchBean.numCustom" theme="simple" cssClass="form"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="bloc3" style="display:none;">
                        <tiles2:insertTemplate template="/operations/Entitlements/struts2/SearchOperatorTile.jsp">
                            <tiles2:putAttribute name="formName" value="MaintenanceLineItemsAdvancedSearchPageForm"/>
                            <tiles2:putAttribute name="propertyName" value="advSearchBean.dateCustomSearchQualifier"/>
                            <tiles2:putAttribute name="propertyType" value="date"/>
                        </tiles2:insertTemplate>
                        <tiles2:insertTemplate template="/operations/common/struts2/simpleDateTile.jsp" flush="true">
                            <tiles2:putAttribute name="formName" type="string" value="MaintenanceLineItemsAdvancedSearchPageForm" />
                            <tiles2:putAttribute name="propertyName" type="string" value="advSearchBean.dateCustom" />
                            <tiles2:putAttribute name="buttonId" type="string" value="dateButton" />
                            <tiles2:putAttribute name="isRequired" type="string" value="true" />
                            <tiles2:putAttribute name="generateTd" type="string" value="false" />
                        </tiles2:insertTemplate>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You want to dynamically repeat the `<div id="block_container">` tag? E.g., on a button click, you'll have `<div id="block_container2">` and so on. Sounds like a JavaScript question.

Comment: yes, I want it to be dynamically repeat the total div block

Comment: But one thing is, it has to carry data to the struts action class

Comment: What is the condition for adding a new div? Do you have an event like adding an element into a list?

Comment: by clicking on a hyperlink it will add another div box

Comment: I have added a picture of my requirement please check

Comment: I'm not a Struts user so there is two scenarios: 1) you `<div>` has some reference to some backing bean attribute => you'll need to maintain a list to avoid attribute conflict (like `myBean.text`) 2) it's a pure HTML output (regardless the used framework) so pure JavaScript can be used. But I guess you're in the situation 1)

Comment: Ok I see. But in this case, let's say you have two rows, how will you make the difference between two `advSearchBean.textCustomSearchQualifier` ? I assume that behind this page, you have a backing bean which keeps the input to do some check (Once again, I do not know Struts so it's based on general knowledge only)

Comment: i am passing the data based on the name of the fields to struts. Yah I have a bean (advSearchBean) which store the data and it has a method textCustomSearchQualifier. Every time while adding a new row i will save the previous data and along with this I want to add a new row

Comment: You'll need a list of `textCustomSearchQualifier` otherwise, the first row information will be lost. More globally, you'll need a list of the object you're using to populate your dropdown lists. Then you can iterate over this list

Comment: Can you post relevant code about your backing bean so that I can see if I can help further?